# Postgres Liquibase : ran despite precondition failure due to onFail='MARK_RAN'

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

Postgres Liquibase throws the following error even though this migration script is already run and nothing changed.  databasechangelog shows that the migration ran again.

```
ran despite precondition failure due to onFail='MARK_RAN': 
          src/main/database/liquibase-changelog.xml : SQL Precondition failed.  Expected '0' got '1'
```

That's how my precondition looks like

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset testuser:DEV-1309_add_offer_fields
--preconditions onFail:MARK_RAN
--precondition-sql-check expectedResult:0 select count(*) from offer_row where name = 'Offer' and version = '6'
```

MY question is why is the migration running again since nothing changed?

Comment: `from order` will throw a syntax error to begin with

Comment: why do you think so? anyway I updated to new table name

Comment: because `order` is a **reserved** keyword, if at all it would need to be `from "order"`

Comment: Hi @VinayaNayak, what version of liquibase are you using, and what platform?  I saw a similar error on Windows due to file path being handled different linux vs. windows.